# How are numbers detected in optical character recognition?

Tags: ocr

I am interested in understanding how optical character recognition works on numbers in particular in an attempt to make my own, such as the logic behind determining a number (it must meet certain requirements)? Are there any resources out there that somewhat describe the algorithm that is used to detect numbers? I imagine it largely is comparing non-whitish pixel locations?

Comment: The OCR algorithm is based on lines recognition. So, start with a simple program that recognizes a segment of line.  Then try to recognize a polyline.

Comment: You might want to read about [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning). Or at least start from the [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) page in Wikipedia.